# Strange notice about a bounty being awarded when it isn't

Tags: discussion, bounty

Regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49456599/does-printf-only-allow-taking-as-first-argument):

- It says "This question has an open bounty worth +100 reputation from dbush ending in 3 days."
- There's no accepted answer.
- The comment at the top of the page says "This means that an answer has already been chosen for the bounty to be awarded to, and no further answers are needed. Please do not add any more answers."

This is all very confusing, what's going on?   If the bounty is already assigned to an answer why doesn't it just show the answer as having received the bounty and the bounty being closed?  And why the prohibition on adding more answers? Is this a bug or a feature?

There's a similar problem on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules) except that there *is* an accepted answer that still doesn't show the bounty award.   Furthermore the answers posted so far fail to address a part of the question and yet it says to not add any more answers.

Comment: So someone [just added that in there](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49456599/4) to "discourage more people from writing answers".  Hrm.

Comment: @Makoto I see, I assumed it was some kind of official site notice since it looked like one!

Comment: Yeah, those edits look totally inappropriate. I'll just roll those back...

Answer (score -3):

A few new users were writing bad answers to the question (see all answers posted on August 16th and later) and I thought I was politely helping them out by noting that the question probably already had an answer that was going to be chosen for the bounty <sup>1</sup>, and that no other answers were needed. I didn't mean that the bounty has already been awarded, just that the person that it will be awarded to has already been chosen.

In hindsight, I probably should've done something else to address the problem.

Sorry.

---

As a side note to answer another part of your question, bounties usually bring more reputation to the question owner and answerers if they're left on for longer. I assume this bounty hasn't been awarded yet so that the owner of the answer being credited (@haccks) can get the most benefit out of it.

---

<sup>1</sup> Here's the bounty reason:

> One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.
>
> Credit to haccks for spelling out the types involved.

Comment: Do you have some basis for assuming the bounty is intended for an existing answer? (As opposed to the bounty offerer perhaps thinking the existing answers are lacking)

Comment: @M.M Yes, the bounty reason. See edit.

Comment: I see. It seems a bit hacky using the bounty system that way, maybe it's a feature SO could consider adding (that people can spend rep to specifically award an existing answer)

Comment: @M.M It's already included when you create a bounty. It's been implemented for a long time.

Comment: Or rework it, then ... the fact that you felt an additional message was necessary and I was confused suggests that improvements are possible

Comment: @M.M That would be useful.